# Xamarin Forms Prism Navigation from TabbedPage behaves as PushModelAsync or the navigation bar disappears

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, tabbedpage

In Tabbed page sample given by *Prism*, I want to navigate from `ViewA` (first tab) to `ViewD`(not the next tab but next navigation page).

I don't understand why *this* removes the navigation bar on the top:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(ViewD));
```

Like `PushModelAsync` instead of `PushAsync`. So that I loose the back button on the navigation tab which is not intended.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that ViewA’s parent is not a `NavigationPage`, the result is that the Navigation Service assumes you want modal Navigation. You simply need to add `useModalNavigation: false`, this will make the Navigation Service push ViewD correctly inside the Navigation Page.